# What is my co-worker asking?

Tags: american-english

My American co-worker sent this to our group chat:

> Can an undatable man be transformed into a datable man?
>
> I am not asking if you think such a thing can be done in real life.
>
> I am asking if a real undatable man can be transformed into a datable man.

English is my second language, and I'm having trouble making sense of the last two lines.

Comment: Cha., I think that  piece have been perfectly arranged to flummox the brain of people, like you, who received and read it, though. If any, respond with an expostulation.

Comment: I think what she's trying to ask is, "I don't really want to try doing it, but do you think it's theoretically possible to make such a transformation?"

Comment: Contrary to what Prof. Lawler suggests in his (solid) answer, I submit that *every single word* of this can be looked up in a dictionary and the meaning is completely straightforward (even to some non-native speakers). However, the more important reason I am putting this on hold is that I fail to understand why you didn't just ask your co-worker. He knows for a fact exactly what he means, and you were talking at him already, and since he's your co-worker you *still can*. There is absolutely no point in asking random strangers off the Internet instead.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Lookupability of individual words notwithstanding, the quote as quoted is utterly meaningless and makes no sense, so I can’t blame the asker for not understanding it. I don’t understand it, either, and nor do several answerers. Still no reason not to just ask the source, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Even if English were your native language, you wouldn't necessarily understand it.
It's American popular culture, and if you're not immersed in that, it's impenetrable.

First, the cues:

- *date* as a verb with a person `P` as direct object refers to courtship and/or sex,
  which may or may not involve `P`, depending on circumstances
- the `V`*-able* suffix forms an absolutive adjective that means
  'capable of `V`-ing', or 'allowed to `V`', both modal notions
- the negative *un-* prefix logically negates the modal *-able*
  (logically, `P` *is un-*`V`-*able* means `NOT (ALLOWED/CAPABLE (V (P)))`, or
  i.e, "`P` is not allowed to `V`" or "`P` is not capable of `V`-ing")

**but**

- all of the above notwithstanding, there **is** no such meaningful word or concept as *undatable*,
  because there is no official dating authority except one's own and one's partners' customs.
  This means the post has to be a joke, and therefore has a different conversational role.

Put them all together, they refer to someone's (whose? obvious first guess, the sender's)
desire -- and repeated failure -- to find a partner of the appropriate sex.

The OQ is worded without clues to anyone's gender, so there is a wide range of circumstances
that it might refer to; therefore the particular context is significant.

In a discussion that is actually **about** dating -- where the subject is already active in the discussion -- this is a mildly self-deprecatory comment, inviting denials and jocular compliments (*Oh, you're not so bad*). Flirting, in other words; it's allowed by the rules of the game. Until it's not.

However, if this is the first mention of dating as a topic, it seems pretty bold in a business forum.  Again, those familiar with the context must judge.

Comment: Shucks. It's pretty straightforward [Pragmatics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragmatics), actually.

Answer (score 1):

Your confusion is perfectly normal.

The first and second sentences kind of "cancel each other out"! How can you speculate whether or not an undatable man is capable of being transformed if you do not think it is possible?  This does not make sense.

Sentences one and three are essentially the same.

Your friend needs to re-word his or her questions for better clarity. There seems to be an unspoken assumption which needs to be brought into the open. I am not exactly sure what it might be.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the whole thing does not follow the laws of logic.  It negates itself and then asks the question.  This falls into meanigless language...and if not into useless language.
I am no psychologist but if this person is serious then I would guess she would fall into the pathetically co-dependent category, or into people who know what the right answer to the question is to them, and need reasurance.

Answer (score 0):

Your friend has made some errors which may hinder your understanding.

First of all, she means "dateable," which refers to a person's potential as a romantic target. A person who is "dateable" has the emotional (and sometimes physical) qualities of his or her gender which make for a favorable option for an extended romantic affair.

In American culture, a man might not be considered dateable for any number of reasons. Some qualities that would make a man "undateable" include slovenliness, immaturity, irresponsibility, poverty or shallowness.

An undateable man may have some qualities, especially physical attractiveness, that make him appealing. A woman might try to fix the man's poor qualities because his virtues or her emotional attachment appeal to her.

Popular myths exist that characterize these men as incapable of change. Your friend is wondering your opinion on whether such a man can be changed.

The second sentence, which others have pointed out as confusing, simply states that the motivation for asking is not advice, but rather curiosity.